# PHP strtotime behaviour

Tags: php, date, unix, datetime, strtotime

The following lines of code returns two different outputs on two different servers A and B:

```
echo date("M Y", strtotime("2015-01"));
echo date("M Y", strtotime("2015-02"));
```

The expected output is "Jan 2015" and "Feb 2015" which is correct on the server A.

But the same code on server B returns the output as "Jan 2015" and "Mar 2015".

On debugging, I found that the `strtotime` function on server B is always returning the timestamp for the current day of every month (today is 29th), which explains why "2015-02" is shown as "March 2015" (since there is no Feb 29, 2015). Yesterday, this code was returning the same output on both servers since Feb 28th is valid and is properly translated to Feb 2015.

So essentially, on server A, the effective code is

```
 echo date("M Y", strtotime("2015-01-01"));
 echo date("M Y", strtotime("2015-02-01"));
```

while on server B, the effective code is

```
echo date("M Y", strtotime("2015-01-29")); //or, strtotime("2015-01-[current day]")
echo date("M Y", strtotime("2015-02-29"));
```

Why is there this difference between these two servers?

Comment: Time zone differences. This is one of many reasons why you shouldn't abuse `strtotime()` like this.

Comment: @Sammitch You're fast... ;)

Comment: @Sammitch I don't think this is timezone issue. How can any timezone be 29 days apart from other? As I mentioned, it is assuming the current day of the month on Server B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with different version of php. There is a BC in php 5.2.7, from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> In PHP 5 prior to 5.2.7, requesting a given occurrence of a given
>   weekday in a month where that weekday was the first day of the month
>   would incorrectly add one week to the returned timestamp. This has
>   been corrected in 5.2.7 and later versions.

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/U8kuF)

Server A has PHP > 5.2.7, server B has PHP < 5.2.7.

Comment: You are correct about the PHP versions on the servers. I don't understand the documentation though. The input to strtotime is only "2015-02" so why would it add the current day to this? The docs say it would incorrectly add one week to the returned timestamp, but in this case it is more than 4 weeks.

Comment: I really don't have any idea about that. There are more strange behavior, in php <= 5.1.6 strtotime returns other value. I think we could investigate,  but we just lose time. In every way.